# RxJava: InterruptedIOException

Tags: rx-java

I wrote some code to download a file from server meanwhile updating progress bar. Downloading code was running in `Schedulers.io` thread and updating ui code was running in `AndroidSchedulers.mainThread`. My program terminated after download began. Here is my code:

```
    Observable
    .create(new Observable.OnSubscribe<String>() {
        @Override
        public void call(Subscriber<? super String> subscriber) {
            try {
                Response response = getResponse(url);
                if (response != null && response.isSuccessful()) {
                    InputStream is = response.body().byteStream();
                    subscriber.onNext(response.body().contentLength()); // init progress
                    File storedFile = Utils.getStoredFile(context, filePath);
                    OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(storedFile);

                    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                    int len;
                    while ((len = is.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                        // write data
                        os.write(buffer, 0, len);

                        count += len;
                        subscriber.onNext(count); // update progress
                    }

                    if (!subscriber.isUnsubscribed()) {
                        subscriber.onCompleted();
                    }

                    os.close();
                    is.close();
                    response.body().close();

            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                subscriber.onError(e);
            }
        }
    })
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()) // io and network operation  
    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()) // UI view update operation  
    .subscribe(new Observer<Long>() {
        @Override
        public void onCompleted() {
            Log.d(TAG, "onCompleted -> " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(Throwable e) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onError -> " + e.getMessage());
        }

        @Override
        public void onNext(Long progress) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onNext -> " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
            Log.d(TAG, "onNext progress -> " + progress);
            // here update view in ui thread
        }
    }
    }
```

And here is error text:

```
java.io.InterruptedIOException: thread interrupted
    at okio.Timeout.throwIfReached(Timeout.java:145)
    at okio.Okio$2.read(Okio.java:136)
    at okio.AsyncTimeout$2.read(AsyncTimeout.java:211)
    at okio.RealBufferedSource.read(RealBufferedSource.java:50)
    at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.HttpConnection$FixedLengthSource.read(HttpConnection.java:418)
    at okio.RealBufferedSource$1.read(RealBufferedSource.java:371)
    at java.io.InputStream.read(InputStream.java:163)
    at com.eldorado.rxfiledownloaddemo.presenter.Presenter$1.call(Presenter.java:74)
    at com.eldorado.rxfiledownloaddemo.presenter.Presenter$1.call(Presenter.java:52)
    at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:8098)
    at rx.internal.operators.OperatorSubscribeOn$1$1.call(OperatorSubscribeOn.java:62)
    at rx.internal.schedulers.ScheduledAction.run(ScheduledAction.java:55)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executor    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:23    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:153)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:267)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

Comment: I think there might be a mistake in your Observable implementation, but I'm not sure where exactly without debugging complete code. According to your StackTrace, something is wrong in line 74 or 52 in your Presenter.java file. Maybe try to use Retrofit (https://github.com/square/retrofit) for HTTP connections instead of implementing your own code for that? It's easy to make a mistake there.

Answer (score 0):

The observerOn is apply to the Observable.create but internaly you're creating a new observable in another thread. So your pipeline never give the monitor to the main thread.
I think your code it's too much complex for what you want to achieve.

Just in case that help you out to understand the concepts of Scheduler

https://github.com/politrons/reactive/blob/master/src/test/java/rx/observables/scheduler/ObservableAsynchronous.java