# InterruptedIOException when switching from mainThread() to io()

Tags: android, concurrency, rx-java, rx-android

I have some code that first has to run on `AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()`, then has to do a HTTP request, so has to run on `Schedulers.io()`, and handle the result on UI, so back to `AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()`.

I receive `InterruptedIOException` when switching from `AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()` to `Scheulers.io()`.

Here's some code:

```
Model model = getModel();

Completable.fromAction(
    new Action0() {
        public void call() {
            mSubject.onNext(model)
        }
    })
    .subscribeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
    .observeOn(Schedulers.io())
    .andThen(fetchFromServer())
    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
    .subscribe(/* handle success and error */);
...
public <T> Single<T> fetchFromServer() {
    Request request = new Request(); // some request from server, not important
    return bodyFrom2(request);
}

public <T> Single<T> bodyFrom2(final Request<T> request) {
    return Single.defer(new Callable<Single<T>>() {
                @Override
                public Single<T> call() throws Exception {
                    try {
                        Response<T> response = request.execute();
                        if (response.error() != null)
                           return Single.error(response.error().getMessage());
                        else {
                            return Single.just(response.body());
                        }
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        return Single.error(e);
                    }
                }
            });
}

public static <T> Single<T> bodyFrom1(final Request<T> request) {
    return Single.create(new Single.OnSubscribe<T>() {
        @Override
        public void call(SingleSubscriber<? super T> subscriber) {
            try {
                Response<T> response = request.execute();
                if (subscriber.isUnsubscribed())
                    return;

                if (response.error() != null)
                    subscriber.onError(response.error().getMessage());
                else {
                    subscriber.onSuccess(response.body());
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                if (subscriber.isUnsubscribed())
                    return;

                subscriber.onError(e);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

The exception is thrown in `bodyFrom()` (1 or 2), at `request.execute()`.
I used `bodyFrom1()`, but I found [this question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37680572/rxjava-interruptedioexception/) and thought about trying with the second one. Regardless, I receive the exception.

Trying to find what and where the problem is, I tried this:

```
Completable.complete()
    .subscribeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
    .observeOn(Schedulers.io())
    .andThen(fetchFromServer())
    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
    .subscribe(/* handle success and error */);
```

which still throws `InterruptedIOException`, and this:

```
Completable.complete()
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.computation())
    .observeOn(Schedulers.io())
    .andThen(fetchFromServer())
    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
    .subscribe(/* handle success and error */);
```

which works fine.

EDIT:

- It seems to work if I'm using `Observable` or `Single` instead of `Completable`.
- Added an issue on RxAndroid's [Github](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxAndroid/issues/322).

Comment: For a workaround, I suggest clearing the flag by Thread.interrupted() before you call execute. Also add another if (s.isUnsubscribed()) before executed to be sure it isn't due to a legitimate unsubscription.

Comment: Thanks, but it didn't work (both methods). I'll add an issue on RxAndroid or RxJava later today. It seems to work if I'm using `Observable` or `Single` instead of `Completable`.